# Differentiable function in some neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define $f(x,y,z)=x^2y+e^x+z$. Show that there exists a differentiable function $g(s,t)$ in some neighborhood of (1,-1) in $R^2$, such that $g(1,-1)=0$ and $f(g(y,z),y,z)=0$!

---

I am trying to do the above but have problem with the differentiable function of $g(s,t)$ which is not match with the variables in $f(x,y,z)$? So any help for solving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: You can change $g(s,t)$ to $g(y,z)$ if you like.  The names of the arguments don't matter.

Comment: The question is an existential one. It is not clear if you are proving the existence using Implicit Function Theorem or trying to get $g$ explicitly. Please clarify.

Comment: Mr Saulspatz ok, so whenever i use g(y,z) it doesn't problem right. To Mr. Murthy yes it was the point that i still confuse any suggestion from where should i start to show? 
so far i get the implicit function will be $\frac{dz}{dx}=-(2xy+e^x)$ and $\frac{dz}{dy}=-x^2$ so that $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{2xy+e^x}{x^2}$.